# How to add custom attributes to mail in OWA?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I need to customize OWA's functionality, add custom properties to the mail, and set/display property values in the edit and read interface, as well as in the mailing list

Answer (score 0):

You can show message details, see [Internet message header in Outlook on the Web, OWA and Outlook.com](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/internet-message-header-in-outlook-on-the-web-owa) for more information.

If you need to add or display any other information I'd suggest creating a web add-in, see [Outlook add-ins overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview) to get started quickly.

Comment: Is there a way to add custom headers?I'm not just showing it.

Comment: You need to develop an add-in.

Comment: Does OWA 2010 support add-on development?I've implemented this in the outlook client, but don't you know how the OWA change solves the problem of OWA 2010 supporting add-on development?I have implemented this function in outlook client, but I don't know how to solve it in OWA

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: There was no mention of OWA 2010 in your original post.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem in OWA2010?
Even in some unofficial way

Comment: No, I don't have any idea. The best what you can do is create a browser extension where you detect the currently selected item and make an EWS request.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I think it should be possible to send the EWS request directly through AJAX, but I'm not sure if I can manipulate the email through EWS before it is sent